# Building Expression Trees

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees

I'm struggling with the idea of how to build an expression tree for more lambdas such as the one below, let alone something that might have multiple statements. For example:

```
Func<double?, byte[]> GetBytes
      = x => x.HasValue ? BitConverter.GetBytes(x.Value) : new byte[1] { 0xFF };
```

I would appreciate any thoughts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest reading through the [list of methods on the Expression class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155837.aspx), all of your options are listed there, and the [Expression Trees Programming Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx).

As for this particular instance:

```
/* build our parameters */
var pX = Expression.Parameter(typeof(double?));

/* build the body */
var body = Expression.Condition(
    /* condition */
    Expression.Property(pX, "HasValue"),
    /* if-true */
    Expression.Call(typeof(BitConverter),
                    "GetBytes",
                    null, /* no generic type arguments */
                    Expression.Member(pX, "Value")),
    /* if-false */
    Expression.Constant(new byte[] { 0xFF })
);

/* build the method */
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<double?,byte[]>>(body, pX);

Func<double?,byte[]> compiled = lambda.Compile();
```

Comment: Thanks for the very clear response...I have been reading about this for some time and seemed to be going around in circles and there always seemed to be missing pieces...

Comment: small note: Expression.Member(...) did not exist in my environment, so needed to change it to Expression.Property(...)