# How would something similar to Telerik's WPF DataFilter Control work?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, reflection, linq-to-entities

Telerik has the following control:

http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/datafilter.aspx

Now this can apparently filter any collection. I haven't used it personally but I'm guessing you can create dynamic queries for Entity Framework (I'm just speculating, if you can not do that, just imagine something similar that can achieve this.)

I am guessing such a thing would get the properties of the class(entity) it is querying using Reflection, and create LINQ queries again using Reflection.

Is there any other way other than Reflection to create a control similar to this that can create dynamic queries given *any* entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a word, [Expression Trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx).

I haven't looked at the source for the component (they do supply the source for the higher subscription levels), but after using their components for a number of years and building extensions to things like their data grid column filters, I would suggest that this component is an evolution of their earlier work.

Related:

- MSDN: [How to: Use Expression Trees to Build Dynamic Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb882637.aspx)
- previous Stack Overflow question: [Building Expression Trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273788/building-expression-trees)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Wouldn't it still need to get the properties of the entity using Reflection to create the Expression Tree?

Comment: @hattenn I don't know enough detail to mention anything here with any reliability, although there are a couple of guys around SO who could answer that question. I've also updated my answer and changed the first link.